# Is condensing 'std::vector<T>&' into just 'T&' is permitted in C++ template?

Tags: c++

I have been using the following overloading of `print_vector` to print out elements of the input array ([1]).

```
//////[1]///////
template<typename T>
void print_vector(T& vec) { // this function is for lagacy arrays in C/C++
                            // e.g. int x[3] = {1,2,3};

  std::cout << "- print vector" << std::endl;
  for (const auto& elem : vec) {
    std::cout << elem << std::endl;
  }
}

template<typename T>
void print_vector(std::vector<T>& vec) {
  std::cout << "- print vector" << std::endl;
  for (const auto& elem : vec) {
    std::cout << elem << std::endl;
  }
}

template<typename T>
void print_vector(thrust::host_vector<T>& vec) {
  std::cout << "- print vector" << std::endl;
  for (const auto& elem : vec) {
    std::cout << elem << std::endl;
  }
}

template<typename T>
void print_vector(thrust::device_vector<T>& vec) {
  std::cout << "- print vector" << std::endl;
  for (const auto& elem : vec) {
    std::cout << elem << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The reason why I did like this was that it seemed to require 'two' types for each function - for example, `std::vector` and `T` for the second one.

But I noticed that the following function [2] alone can do the desired functions for all types of inputs.

```
//////[2]///////

template<typename T>
void print_vector(T& vec) {
  std::cout << "- print vector" << std::endl;
  for (const auto& elem : vec) {
    std::cout << elem << std::endl;
  }
}
```

At the first glance, it seems that it had overly condensed two types into one `T`, so I thought this should be something like

```
//////[3]///////

template<typename T1, typename T2>
void print_vector(T1<T2>& vec) {
  std::cout << "- print vector" << std::endl;
  for (const auto& elem : vec) {
    std::cout << elem << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Is using [2] function to represent function overloadings in [1] in C++ is standard? Or is it somehow a coincidence that [2] worked properly?

And the fact still confuses me is that the ranged-for `for (const auto& elem : vec) {}` is applicable to legacy C/C++ arrays. When I search for the ranged-for, I found this sentence - `"defined as anything that you can iterate through—for example, std::vector, or any other C++ Standard Library sequence whose range is defined by a begin() and end()"`. Although the pointers and iterators are quite similar, they are not the same and the lagacy arrays do not have 'iterators' that can be accessed by begin(), and end() but still ranged-for works. Why?

#### ADDED

Thanks to 273K, I feel I am getting closer but still cannot get some points.

For example the following code works fine with the `vec.begin()` part being commented.

```
template<typename T>
void print_vector(T& vec) {
  //std::cout << vec.begin() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "- print vector" << std::endl;
  for (const auto& elem : vec) {
    std::cout << elem << std::endl;
  }
}

int main(void) {

  int x[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  print_vector(x);

  return 0;
}
```

But when I turn on the commented line, I met the following errors during compilation.

```
main.cu(12): error: expression must have class type but it has type "int *"
          detected during instantiation of "void print_vector(T &) [with T=int [5]]"
```

So, could you give a little more explanation on your words - "There are common std::begin(c) and std::end(c) for all containers and T(&)[N]." ?

Comment: **lagacy arrays do not have 'iterators'** There are common `std::begin(c)` and `std::end(c)` for all containers and `T(&)[N]`. See [std::begin, std::cbegin (2)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin). **is standard?** Using (1) and (2) approaches for your `print_vector()` is standard.

Comment: @273K, sorry for confusion, when I said 'lagacy arrays', I meant simple arrays declared via `int x[3] = {1,2,3};`-wise. Still these simple arrays have iterators?

Comment: `T(&)[N]` with `T` is `int` and `N` is `3` is a type of the parameter `vec` of `void print_vector(T& vec)` when you pass the raw array `int x[3]`.

Comment: @273K, Thanks for very quick responses. But still I am not getting it. Could you see added parts of the previous question? I had added some more.

Comment: `std::begin(arr)` works for both `std::vector<int> arr` and for `int arr[5]`. `arr.begin()` only works for `std::vector<int> arr`.

Comment: Single overload `template<typename T> void print_vector(T& vec)` with range for loop will work for array and *all* types of vectors.

Comment: It's not a case of "compressing `std::vector<T>` into a `T` in a template.   It's the fact that, if an argument is a `std::vector<anything>` that both forms of your template match.   The differerence is that the function which accepts `T &` will match ANYTHING (a `std::list<T>`, a `std::vector<T>`, etc) but the one which accepts a `std:vector<T> &` will ONLY match a `std::vector`.   And, BTW, legacy arrays DO have iterators that can be used in a range-based `for` (one of the `std::begin()` overloads introduced in C++11 [the same standard that introduced range-based for loops] works with them).

Comment: @Peter, Thanks. Then how about dynamically allocated arrays? I believe `std::vector` things will update the information of their size whenever I change the numer of elements, but dynamically-allocated legacy arrays will not have size information. Also, pointers generated via `thrust::device_ptr<T>` also does not work with `print_vector(&T vec)`. With `thrust::device_ptr<T>`,  I should provide the number of elements to `print_vector` and explicitly write `for (int i=0;i<N;i++) {}`, right?

Comment: There is no `std::begin()` for a pointer, and nor should there be, since there is no way - given only a raw pointer - of determining if it points at (the first element of) an array or something else.   I suspect you have fallen for the perennial beginner trap of believing that a pointer is an array.

Comment: @Peter, Indeed it is always confusing how C's treat arrays and pointers lol... But when we declare an array as `int x[3]`, the `x` is the pointer to the very first element of the array, and we access its elements via `[]` operation as `x[2] = *(x+2)`. Then if we pass `x` as an argument to `function (T& x)`, then aren't we passing the address of the first element of `x`? (Yes, here I got another confusing understandings on all the pointers vs referece, though)

Comment: When you want to operate on both arrays and containers, use `std::begin(vec)` and `std::end(vec)` instead of `vec.begin()` and `vec.end()`.

Comment: @SangjunLee  You're definitely not understanding.  Given a declaration `int x[3]`, `x` is not a pointer.   Your misunderstanding is that, in *some* contexts, using `x` in an expression (e.g. `x + 2`) converts it to a pointer, but in other contexts that isn't true.    (The beginner mistake comes down to believing that is always true).  Passing `x` as an argument to your `function(T &x)` does NOT pass the address of the first element on `x`.   It passes a reference to `x` (with type `int (&)[3]`) which is NOT a pointer at all.

Comment: ... so what @Peter says is that `std::begin(vec)` will work just fine inside `print_vector`.

Comment: @Peter, so helpful very thank you. One very last question. Then, when I pass an argument as reference, it is not 'copy', right? Therefore the speed of the function will be the same order as passing via pointer?

Comment: Yes, passing an argument by reference does not pass a copy.   What that means for performance (say, compared with passing a pointer) depends on a lot of things.    You can be certain that passing a reference is less expensive than passing a large object - or a set of large objects - by value.   How it compares with passing a pointer (say, to the first element of an array) is really up to the implementation.  If such performance differences matter (sadly, too many beginners focus on performance more than necessary, so do premature optimisation) then MEASURE performance and profile your code.

Comment: @SangjunLee Yes, taking an argument by reference will not create a copy. In some situations a conversion is needed though, which will create a temporary object. Example: `foo(const std::string& str)` and if you call it with `foo("Hello");` then a temporary `std::string` will be created.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, ah ha! Those are the case when the given input type does not exactly match the defined argument type, but there is a proper Constructor in the class?

Comment: @SangjunLee Exactly! Since `std::string` has an implicit conversion constructor for `const char*` it'll use that (in my example above).

Comment: You don't want `vec.begin()` - you want `std::begin(vec)` which will work with arrays and vectors both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way of explaining it. The range-based for loop merely exists to let you write simpler loops in case you don't need the value of an index, pointer or iterator. Your example, through the magic of the std::begin and std::end abstractions, is essentially the same as [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/cMfvPEMvj):

```
#include <iostream>

void print_vector(int (&vec)[5]) {
  for (const int* elem = vec; elem != vec + 5; ++elem) {
    std::cout << *elem << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  int x[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  print_vector(x);
}
```

Which looks like an eclectic mix of C and C++. Although C++ allows you to create references to C-style arrays, those don't have member functions because that was not really a thing in C. So when you try to call one, the C-style array does what it does best and implicitly converts into a pointer, which is still not a class type and fails the compilation.